# Making a Name Formatter

Tags: python, python-2.7

Writing a program that asks for a name in the format of (Last, Middle First) and creates an output as (First Middle Last). I understand the input and output features I just don't know how to give the names indexes to then output them in the different format.

EDIT: To make this a little easier to understand, I just want to be able to give the words they input into three different variables I can later re-arrange when printing differently.

Its a very short code I have so far

```
    Name = raw_input("Enter your name as Last, Middle, First: ")
    print Name[2]
```

What my problem is that its printing the index as individual characters and I want to print them as different words. So for example print Name[2] would print the entire middle name.

I dont want an entire code, just a way to make these three words that they input as variables or index's I can later rearrange

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Can you tell us anything about what you tried and what results you've gotten?

Comment: I think a little more detail is needed

Comment: Yeah Im sorry I should be more specific. What I tried doing was making it into a string and then outputting it as different index's but it doesn't work since you cant predict how long each word is going to be. I just want to know how to give each of the three words a variable you can print later in a different format.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant part of your code. How did you try to split the names?

Comment: You wrote one short line of code and want us to fill in the rest? Please review your instructional materials or find a tutorial online (the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) is quite good).

Comment: TigerhawkT3 its an extremely short program and I never asked to fill in the rest. Im just asking for a way to give each of the three words the user inputs a variable or index so I can rearrange. I will review the tutorial since I am very new to this. Im sure the solution is extremely simple but im just not experienced.

Answer (score 0):

so you need something like this?

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
nl = name.split()

nl.reverse()
print(*nl)
```

Comment: Why the `list()` call?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I forgot that `str.split()` will giving a list :P